# How do I access logs from the past day with os_log from Apple Watch?

Tags: watchos

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue on watchOS.

I'm not sure how to reproduce the problem I'm seeing, but I do encounter it occasionally during testing on a real device in the wild, so I'm trying to use `os_log` in order to diagnose the problem after the fact.

As a first step, to make sure I understand how how to write to the log and access it later, I've attempted to log an event any time the app first loads.

In the `ExtensionDelegate.swift` file for my app, I added this:

```
import os.log

extension OSLog {
    private static var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
    
    static let health = OSLog(subsystem: subsystem,
                              category: "health")
}
```

Then, I updated the `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegate function with this:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    os_log("App Started",
           log: OSLog.health,
           type: .error)
}
```

I know it's not really an error message, but from what I've read, messages that are not `.error` are not written to saved to the log for later. I want to make sure it gets written to the log like a real error would.

I installed [the sysdiagnose profile](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=sysdiagnose), then installed the the most recent version of my app.

After testing the app for the day, I attempted to export the file. Following the instructions I've found elsewhere, I produced a sysdiagnose on Apple Watch by holding the Digital Crown and Side button for two seconds (and felt the haptic feedback when I released).

Then, I put the watch on the charger for a few minutes per [the instructions here](https://download.developer.apple.com/iOS/watchOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf), which recommended 15 minutes.

I opened the **Watch** app on my paired iPhone, then went to General > Diagnostic Logs and downloaded the sysdiagnose from Apple Watch, and sent it to my computer with AirDrop.

This gave me a tarball file (for example, `sysdiagnose_2021.03.05_17-01-57-0700_Watch-OS_Watch_18S801.tar.gz`). Once I decompressed that, I had a folder of lots of files and subfolders.

After poking around in this folder, I figured my best bet was to look in the `system_logs.logarchive` file. I opened that in the macOS **Console** app, set the *Showing* dropdown to *All Messages*, and looked around the time I opened the app. I didn't see any log output from my app.

I also filtered for "App Started" (the log message from my app) and didn't find anything.

Then, I filtered by *category* for "health" and didn't find the event I had logged.

Is `system_logs.logarchive` the correct place to be looking for the log output from my app?

If not, where should I be looking? Or what am I doing wrong?

I really want a better understanding of how I can log messages on Apple Watch so I can view them later so I can make my Apple Watch apps more robust, but I'm at a dead end.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Or am I setting up the logging wrong? Or is it something else? I would appreciate any guidance about this!

Comment: Did you manage to find out what was wrong? I'm about to start adding some logging to my Apple Watch app to hopefully help diagnose some hard to reproduce issues.

Comment: @bencallis No, I never got it working. Please let me know if you do.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Apple Dev Forms, [sysdiagnose](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=sysdiagnose) allows you to view the logs on your apple watch.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I described that I did, but then where do I look to find the actual log output?